# Producing a list of all the pairs can be made by from two lists of equal length

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

I have two lists:

```
{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}
```

and

```
{y1, y2, y3, y4, y5}
```

How can I get a list like the one below from them, where each element in the first list is paired with each element in the second?

> `{{x1, y1}, {x1, y2}, {x1, y3}, ..., {x2, y1}, {x2, y2}, ..., {x5, y5}}`

Can I avoid using `Table` to do it?

Comment: `Outer` is made for this. Here, `Outer[List, xlist, ylist]` does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html):

```
Tuples[{{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5} , {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5}}]
(* {{x1, y1}, {x1, y2}, {x1, y3}, {x1, y4}, {x1, y5}, {x2, 
  y1}, {x2, y2}, {x2, y3}, {x2, y4}, {x2, y5}, {x3, y1}, {x3, 
  y2}, {x3, y3}, {x3, y4}, {x3, y5}, {x4, y1}, {x4, y2}, {x4, 
  y3}, {x4, y4}, {x4, y5}, {x5, y1}, {x5, y2}, {x5, y3}, {x5, 
  y4}, {x5, y5}} *)
```

> Can I avoid using `Table` to do it?

Actually I don't think `Table` is bad for this if you use the right syntax.  I don't think it's any worse than `Outer`.

```
xx = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5};

yy = {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5};

Table[{x, y}, {x, xx}, {y, yy}]
(* {{{x1, y1}, {x1, y2}, {x1, y3}, {x1, y4}, {x1, y5}}, {{x2, 
   y1}, {x2, y2}, {x2, y3}, {x2, y4}, {x2, y5}}, {{x3, y1}, {x3, 
   y2}, {x3, y3}, {x3, y4}, {x3, y5}}, {{x4, y1}, {x4, y2}, {x4, 
   y3}, {x4, y4}, {x4, y5}}, {{x5, y1}, {x5, y2}, {x5, y3}, {x5, 
   y4}, {x5, y5}}} *)

Catenate[%]
(* {{x1, y1}, {x1, y2}, {x1, y3}, {x1, y4}, {x1, y5}, {x2, 
  y1}, {x2, y2}, {x2, y3}, {x2, y4}, {x2, y5}, {x3, y1}, {x3, 
  y2}, {x3, y3}, {x3, y4}, {x3, y5}, {x4, y1}, {x4, y2}, {x4, 
  y3}, {x4, y4}, {x4, y5}, {x5, y1}, {x5, y2}, {x5, y3}, {x5, 
  y4}, {x5, y5}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you could achieve this result: the `Outer` function is probably easiest.  For example,

```
xlist={x1,x2,x3,x4,x5};ylist={y1,y2,y3,y4,y5};
result=Outer[{#1,#2}&,xlist,ylist]
```

This will have extra layers of braces relative to the output you want: you could get rid of them by applying `Flatten[result,1]`.

Comment: Suggest `Outer[{#1, #2} &, xlist, ylist] // Catenate`, rather than `Flatten`.

Comment: @m_goldberg In older versions `Catenate` is slower than `Join @@` on packed arrays.  (I was surprised when people told me about this.)  Not sure about `Flatten[..., 1]`.  I do prefer the `Catenate` syntax.